# Android - Weight Picker

Tags: java, android, uipickerview, picker, numberpicker

I come from iOS and Swift and I don't really know how I could replace simply the `PickerView`.

In my app, the user should be able to define its weight (for example 75.6kg).

The best way to do that seems to be like that:
[image]

Given that I'm new in Android I don't really know how to reproduce that. I made some research and it seems to be a `NumberPicker`? But I don't know how I could have these two distincts columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can achieve something similar with a little customization through the usage of two `NumberPicker`s positioned side by side:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/first_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/CustomNumberPickerTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/second_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/CustomNumberPickerTheme" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To better match the screenshot a `TextView` was included in between the two `NumberPicker`s as the decimal point along with a custom theme `CustomNumberPickerTheme` which you'll need to set inside `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    ...

    <style name="CustomNumberPickerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```